# ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: google-chrome

My website often (not every time) displays blank page (only in Chrome).

Console show error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Also, check this video: https://adobe.ly/2nFZadN

I know that I can fix in Chrome preferences, but how to fix it for my visitors?

Comment: have same problem.. in 2020